# How to emit an socket event from one file and listen to it from another file?

Tags: laravel, sockets, websocket, socket.io, real-time

```
 io.on('connection',(socket)=>{
 console.log('connection');

 socket.on('connected',(userid)=>{
       users[userid]= socket.id;
 });

 socket.on('updatecurr',()=>{
    console.log('request');
    socket.emit('wel');
    console.log('and anse'); 
 });
});
```

This is my server code. Here i want to listen to event updatecurr from one file listen its reponse wel in another file.
Emitter file code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Emitter</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.6.0/socket.io.min.js" integrity="sha384-c79GN5VsunZvi+Q/WObgk2in0CbZsHnjEqvFxC5DxHn9lTfNce2WW6h2pH6u/kF+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Emitter</h1>
    <button id="updateButton">Update</button>

    <script>
        // Connect to the Socket.IO server
        const socket = io('http://localhost:3000');

        // Trigger the 'updatecurr' event when the button is clicked
        const updateButton = document.getElementById('updateButton');
        updateButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            socket.emit('updatecurr');
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Reciever File code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Receiver</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.6.0/socket.io.min.js" integrity="sha384-c79GN5VsunZvi+Q/WObgk2in0CbZsHnjEqvFxC5DxHn9lTfNce2WW6h2pH6u/kF+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Receiver</h1>
    <div id="messageDisplay"></div>

    <script>
        // Connect to the Socket.IO server
        const socket = io('http://localhost:3000');

        // Listen for the 'wel' event from the server
        socket.on('wel', (data) => {
            console.log('Received data:', data);
            // Update the message display with the received data
            const messageDisplay = document.getElementById('messageDisplay');
            messageDisplay.innerHTML = `Received update!`;
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here the problem is that my reciver doesnot recieves reponse when even is emitted by another file.
the response is only recieved when the event is emitted from the same file.
Now how to solve it???

Here i expected to receive the response of event emitted from another file but it isn't?